# bash script which downloads a file with sftp

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, sh, expect

I need to make a sftp connection with a password and download a file. There is an ip restriction so first of all i should make a ssh connection. I wrote a script but it stucks after connecting with ssh.

Note: i also tried doing it with an expect script but it also didn't work.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/
ssh test@test1.t.com
lftp sftp://test2:123456@test2.com
get "file.xls"
```

Edit: You can also see my expect code here.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect -f
expect -c "
spawn ssh test@test1.t.com
expect \"test\@test1\:\~\$\"
spawn sftp test2@test2.com
expect \"*assword:\"
send \"123456\r\"
expect \"sftp\>\"
send \"get file.xls\r\" 
expect \"sftp\>\" 
exit 1
";
```

Comment: Have you considered using scp, which uses the same protocols as ssh and sftp??

Comment: @ryekayo test2 needs a sftp connection which requires a password, scp doesn't work...

Comment: @klakson1345 : Can you post your `expect` code so that we can try to find what went wrong ?

Comment: @4ae1e please show me how can you use scp with a password required connection

Comment: @Dinesh you can see it now, thanks.

Comment: Adding `exp_internal 1` might help and post the debug info. One observation. Since you are using the script as an `expect` script directly, there is no need to enclose it within `expect -c`. That is advised only when you are enclosing the expect within shell script.

Comment: @Dinesh when i don't enclose with  expect -c i get command not found errors.

Comment: @Dinesh thansk for the exp_internal 1 advice, but i still count figure it out. look like it cannot connect to test2. test2 has an ip restriction so it can only be accessed from test1. i feel like my expect stript is trying to log in to test2 from my local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish here. First, I'll address the problems in your expect script. Since your shebang line invokes expect, you don't need to wrap the expect body in a call to expect. That gets rid of all the backslashes. Next, you have 2 spawn calls, which raises questions about you're intent. I'm going to assume that you want to ssh to `test1`, then grab the file from `test2` so the file exists on `test1`. This assumption changes the 2nd spawn to a plain `send` command.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect -f

set shell_prompt "test@test1:~$"
set sftp_prompt "sftp>" 

spawn ssh test@test1
expect $shell_prompt
send "sftp test2@test2\r"
expect "*assword:"
send "123456\r"
expect $sftp_prompt
send "get file.xls\r" 
expect $sftp_prompt
send "exit\r"
expect $shell_prompt
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

Now, you can `scp` the file to your local machine. Let's put those 2 steps into one shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

expect <<'EXPECT_SCRIPT'
    set shell_prompt "test@test1:~$"
    set sftp_prompt "sftp>" 

    spawn ssh test@test1
    expect $shell_prompt
    send "sftp test2@test2\r"
    expect "*assword:"
    send "123456\r"
    expect $sftp_prompt
    send "get file.xls\r" 
    expect $sftp_prompt
    send "exit\r"
    expect $shell_prompt
    send "exit\r"
    expect eof
EXPECT_SCRIPT

scp test@test1:file.xls .
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice example to combine expect and bash

Comment: do you have any idea how can use the parameter from shell script in the expect <<'EXPECT_SCRIPT' part?  I tried spawn ssh $user@$server, it dose not work

Comment: In the shell part, export the variables into the enironment `export user=someone server=somewhere`, then in the expect code, reference the environment variables with `ssh $env(user)@$env(server)`